# Add new user and site per front end form

Tags: plugin-recommendation, forms, multisite, user-registration

Do you know any multisite plugin which allows users to create a user account and a site after a form submission. After the form submission, the form will automatically add a site in the network admin and create a new user. Is this possible? Some say that it needs hardcoding for it to work. But I have no idea how to. Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a form, same as contact or custom content from frontend  and send the content of field with the WP core function `wp_insert_user()` to WP, add the users.

an example without form, only a function to insert users and see the fields for the data array.

```
function fb_wp_insert_user() {
    $user_data = array(
        'ID' => '',
        'user_pass' => wp_generate_password(),
        'user_login' => 'dummy',
        'user_nicename' => 'Dummy',
        'user_url' => '',
        'user_email' => 'dummy@example.com',
        'display_name' => 'Dummy',
        'nickname' => 'dummy',
        'first_name' => 'Dummy',
        'user_registered' => '2010-05-15 05:55:55',
        'role' => get_option('default_role') // Use default role or another role, e.g. 'editor'
    );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
}
```

I think is an good idea, that you check the user, before you add the entry on email or name. But you can also update via function: `wp_update_user()`

- see also [this post](http://wpengineer.com/2054/create-users-automatically-in-wordpress/) for more information

Comment: thanks. this one worked for me. this would be a big help. ;p

Comment: Thank you for this code. Please can you tell us how to create a subsite for that specific user, from front end?

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers i know a premium plugin that could do what you seek. It's actually the [Multisite integration](https://profilepress.net/downloads/multisite/) ProfilePress extension.